# Matplotlib: Arrow heads at each vertex in Path

Tags: python, matplotlib, path

I am trying to plot the path taken by some input function (whose vertices are recorded in a numpy array)

I want to add an arrow-head (any direction marker) for every vertex of the form "→→→→" to track the direction of path.

I know the FancyArrowPatch which adds only one arrow-head a the terminal vertex, of the form: "————>". That's **NOT** what I want. [for reasons that are outside the scope of this question]

Currently, my code looks like this: Note, we can't guess the direction.

```
def plot_track(self, verts: np.array) -> None:
    '''Plot followed track: verts is 2D array: x, y'''
    track = Path(verts)
    patch = PathPatch(path=track, edgecolor="#FF0000",
                      fill=False)
    self.axs.add_patch(patch)
    self.fig.canvas.draw()
    self.root.mainloop()
```

[image: Output-link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.patches.Arrow` can be used to draw arrows. A loop needs to visit each vertex and its successor. A similar approach can be used with `FancyArrowPatch`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arrow
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch, Path, Arrow
import numpy as np

def plot_track(verts, ax, **kw_args):
    '''Plot followed track: verts is 2D array: x, y'''
    for xy0, xy1 in zip(verts[:-1], verts[1:]):
        patch = Arrow(*xy0, *(xy1 - xy0), **kw_args)
        ax.add_patch(patch)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(2, 11, 1)
x = t * np.sin(t)
y = t * np.cos(t)
verts = np.vstack([x, y]).T

plot_track(verts - np.array([7, 0]), ax, color='red', fill=True, width=1)
plot_track(verts + np.array([7, 0]), ax, color='red', fill=False, width=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, that will work.
That method (looping multiple patches) was in my mind, but being new at this, I considered myself to be too ignorant to know about availability of something like a vertex connection modifier.